# show/hide and clear the radio button value when hidden in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show/hide the radio button when a radio button is checked and when the radio button is hidden i need to clear the value of radio button when hidden
Here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show2(){
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
  
}
function show1(){
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display ='none';
}
</script>

      <label><input type="radio" name="a1" class="mass" id="mass3"   value="Mass Sponsors" onclick="show1();"> Mass1 Sponsors <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>5000</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="a1" class="mass" id="mass2"   value="Mass Intention" onclick="show2();"> Mass Intention <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"  ></i>150/- or 200/-</label>

   <div id="div1" class="hide">
   <div class="radio">
<label><input type="radio" name="a2"  id="a1" class="mass" value="100"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>100</label>
         <label><input type="radio" name="a2" class="mass" id="a2"   value="150">  <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>150</label>
 <label><input type="radio" name="a2"  id="amount4" class="mass" value="200"> <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>200</label>
 
</div>
```

Comment: But your code works according to your requirement. What is the specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
function show1() {
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
  var ele = document.getElementsByName("a2");
  for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++)
    ele[i].checked = false;
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function show2() {
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';

}

function show1() {
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
  var ele = document.getElementsByName("a2");
  for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++)
    ele[i].checked = false;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="a1" class="mass" id="mass3"   value="Mass Sponsors" onclick="show1();"> Mass1 Sponsors <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>5000</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="a1" class="mass" id="mass2"   value="Mass Intention" onclick="show2();"> Mass Intention <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"  ></i>150/- or 200/-</label>

<div id="div1" class="hide">
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="a2"  id="a1" class="mass" value="100"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>100</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="a2" class="mass" id="a2"   value="150">  <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>150</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="a2"  id="amount4" class="mass" value="200"> <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>200</label>

  </div>
</div>
```